# Assigning random texture to a surface in Blender

Tags: graphics, blender, blender-2.67

I would like to synthesize a (very) long corridor in Blender, where the texture of the walls and ceiling are based on a random noise model (so that it is pretty much unique at any point along the corridor). Is this possible? Ideally, I would like to control the random texture programmatically. I am quite new to Blender but couldn't see an easy way to do it - if you can think of one, please help! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you approach it would depend on the texture you are using and how much control you want. Guessing that you are duplicating an object/s (or using an array) to get he length you could use global mapping instead of object mapping to prevent each object looking the same.

Other options vary from pyDrivers to osl scripts.

You will probably find more help at [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/) but start with more specific questions like How do I hide this seam between each object? or How can I use global X value to choose between two image textures?